# Maximum width of a tag

Tags: tables, design, labels, tags, size

I would like to ask if there's a a common value to the maximum width of a tag? Thanks

[image]

Comment: No that I know.

Answer (score 2):

Tags typically are displayed together to provide weak but indexable context regarding the post. The information inside the tags is as important as the group as a whole. That is to say, for a typical instagram post with the (hash)tags `#beach #waves #analog-photography #sun #sponsored #hunter-gatherer` and so on, you could decide to shorten it

`#beach #waves #analog… #sun #sponso… #hunter…`

– or –

`#beach #waves #analog-photography [show more…]`

and lose similar amounts of information.

Given the choice between these options, the second tends to be more flexible as it can account for both tag length and number of tags, while the first has trouble dealing with large amounts of tags. As such, there's not too much point in having a max tag length usually, so there's no standard "max tag width".

---

Or to put the initial question in reverse: why *should* there be a maximum width for a tag? Tags by their nature tend to be reasonably short; the longest one this site uses may be something like [context-sensitive-help](/questions/tagged/context-sensitive-help), [competitive-analysis](/questions/tagged/competitive-analysis) or [human-interface-guideline](/questions/tagged/human-interface-guideline).

What would be gained from truncating tags in a tag list, outside of creating opportunities for *hilarious* truncation mishaps like `[competitive-anal…]`?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to defining the size of each element the rule of thumb is to see if the element is clickable or not? So in your case because the tags are supposed to be clickable, I would say the size should be defined based on the standard proper size for buttons. You can see the suggested size based on Google Material design library [here](https://m2.material.io/components/buttons#specs)
Btw, I don't think there's anything like the Maximum size, most standards talk about the minimum size and you have to decide how big your elements should be.